# How do i do a automated UIPATH process where i can sum the values in different sheets based on product?

Tags: uipath

I have 3 sheets which contain 3 products and I need to sum the number of products in different sheets together. However, the number of sheets is not fixed. So how can I do an automated UIPATH process which will help me add the sum based on products depending on how much sheet is present in the excel folder?

Comment: What did you try so far? This is a very simple question and a quick search engine search would get you the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that all the worksheets have the same schema, so you could open your file Excel and read every time all the worksheets contained with "Get Workbook Sheets". Then read the range of every worksheet and merge these into one data table. Finally, you can find the sum of the products with LINQ or another query from the data table.

Something like this:
[image]

For example, LINQ query:
dt.AsEnumerable.Where(Function(x) x("colName").Equals("products")).Sum(Function(x) Decimal.Parse(x("colName").ToString))

Regards, Gio